# error: The argument type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

List:

```dart
List<Quotes> qt = [
  Quotes(quotes: "It’s not a bug; it’s an undocumented feature.", author: "Anonymous"),
  Quotes(quotes: "First, solve the problem. Then, write the code.", author: "John Johnson"),
  Quotes(quotes: "Code is like humor. When you have to explain it, it’s bad.", author: "Cory House"),
  Quotes(quotes: "Clean code always looks like it was written by someone who cares.", author: "Robert C. Martin"),
  Quotes(quotes: "Programmer: A machine that turns coffee into code.", author: "Anonymous"),
  Quotes(quotes: "When I wrote this code, only God and I understood what I did. Now only God knows.", author: "Anonymous"),
  Quotes(quotes: "If debugging is the process of removing bugs, then programming must be the process of putting them in.", author: "Sam Redwine"),
];
```

WIDGET:

```
Widget quoteTemplate(qt){
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [

            Text(
              qt.quotes,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.grey[600],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Text(
              qt.author,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.grey[600],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

`StatefulWidget`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Title(
        color: Colors.indigo,
        child: Text(
          "Awesome Quotes",
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: qt.map((q) => quoteTemplate(qt)).toList(),
  );
}
```

Error:

```
The argument type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'.
```

I tried to make a `Widget` which return `Card`. I am trying to return list in that `Card`. I'm learning Flutter so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You're inside a `Scaffold` widget and the `body` attribute takes a Widget

- `qt.map((q) => quoteTemplate(q)).toList()` returns a `List<Widget>`
- Therefore, you're assigning a `List<Widget>` to the `body` attribute, instead of a `Widget`, that's why you're getting this error.

#### And there are two ways to go about it

- You can either `Wrap` the List of widgets returned from the map operation with a Column, just like so

```html
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Title(
        color: Colors.indigo,
        child: Text(
          "Awesome Quotes",
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: Column(
           children: qt.map((q) => quoteTemplate(qt)).toList(),
           )
  );
}
```

- Or you can use a `ListView.builder()`

```html
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Title(color: Colors.indigo, child: Text("Awesome Quotes",)),
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: qt.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final qoute = qt[index];
              return quoteTemplate(qoute);
            },
          ),
);
}
}
```

#### Using the second option, `ListView.Builder()` is better because it is more efficient than spreading widgets.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried the Column one and it worked.. But I have a Question: When I wrote : qt.map  line inside children [ ... ]  it still gave me the Error but when I removed the Square Brackets it worked.. why is that?

Comment: Because it's already a list , if you use [] it would be list inside a list ie nested list, which is again wrong . You can see my post for the simplest solution

Comment: Juste use spread operator before qt.map! ```...qt.map```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in `Column`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Title(color: Colors.indigo, child: Text("Awesome Quotes")),
    ),
    body: Column(           //  Add column here
      children: qt.map((q) => quoteTemplate(q)).toList(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Title(color: Colors.indigo, child: Text("Awesome Quotes",)),
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: qt.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final qoute = qt[index];
              return quoteTemplate(qoute);
            },
          ),
);
}
}
```